# OpenCL kernel won't compile if index of array member is calculated by a function or expression

Tags: opencl

I'm writing a N-body (galaxy) simulator using OpenCL and OpenGL. In the OpenCL kernel code is a line where the index of an array member is calculated by a function as follows: `array[indx(i,j)]`. The kernel is compiling OK on an integrated Intel's graphics card, but it fails to compile on a dedicated NVidia graphics card. Error code -11 is returned by clBuildProgram(), but the build log is empty, although log string size is reported to be 16 characters long. Possibly a bug in NVidia's driver? I have tried to run the code on a third integrated Intel's graphics card and it says "Invalid operation.", also -11 error code is returned. Why does this kernel compile on one card, but fails to compile on other two cards?

I have tried to drop `indx()` function and replace `array[indx(i,j)]` with `array[(j * (j - 1) / 2 + i)]`. It still does not compile on other two cards.

```
unsigned long long indx(unsigned long long i, unsigned long long j)
{
    return (j * (j - 1) / 2 + i);
}

kernel void propagate(global float4* pos, global float4* vel, global float* acc_matr)
{
    constant float mass = 0.00009f;

    for (unsigned long long j = i + 1; j < get_global_size(0); j++)
    {
        float r = distance(pos[i], pos[j]);

        if (r > 0.05f)
        {
            acc_matr[indx(i, j)] = mass / r / r / r;
        }
        else
        {
            acc_matr[indx(i, j)] = -0.5f;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The variable `i` is not declared in your `propagate` kernel function. Is that a copy-paste error? If so, please provide the missing code. Also, have you tried performing the index calculation before `if (r > 0.05f)` and put the result in a temporary variable?

Comment: Just add an error checking like if indx >= 0 before every array indexing then it should accept it

Comment: If it is a matrix then why isnt it indexing as width x j + i ?